# Can i use nextjs api routes for both web and mobile app?

Tags: api, next.js, mobile-application

I want to develop a ***web*** application in Nextjs and a ***mobile*** application later in the future.

can i use nextjs api for both web and mobile version?

> *NOTE*: I can't use ReactJS because the website needs full SEO, thus I must use NextJS to handle that.

Thank u guys for answering me

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can!!!

Try look for Capacitor and Ionic, which are tools to incapsulate web code into mobile applications.
This article could help you during the first approach:
[nextjs and capacitor](https://devdactic.com/nextjs-and-capacitor)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).